# When is the function f(x)=$\alpha x(1-x)$ a contraction?

Tags: real-analysis

When is the function f(x)=$\alpha x(1-x)$ a contraction (x $\in$ [0, 1])? What values of alpha are possible?

Comment: I said it is a contraction, instead of contradiction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$f(x) - f(y) = a(x-y)(1-(x-y)) = a(x-y)(1-x-y)$.  Now, the maximum for $g = (1-x+y)$ over the range $[0,1]$ can be found using the gradient.  We have $g_x = -1, g_y =-1$, so there are no interior critical points.  The critical point must occur on the boundary, with max absolute value $1$.  Thus, for $a <1$ we get a contraction.

Comment: Ok.  This works on $[0,\lambda]$, for any $0< \lambda <1$.

Comment: I did not see the interval $[0,1]$. Sorry.

Comment: No, you are correct.  As the question is written, this cannot be a contraction on the whole interval.